# Laravel 8 Jetstream Inertia All Inertia requests must receive a valid Inertia response

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I've been trying to find the correct answer for my problem I know that the question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65535729/all-inertia-requests-must-receive-a-valid-inertia-response-however-a-plain-json) and actually many other places, but no answers I found could suit my problem.

**The vue component**

```
FooterNewsletter.vue

<template>
    <div class="lg:w-2/4 md:w-1/2 w-full px-8 border-l-2">
        <p class="font-bold text-3xl">
            Don't want to miss the latest cryptocurrency news?
        </p>
        <p class="py-3 text-lg">
            Get the latest news and updates by subscribing to our free
            newsletter 
        </p>
        <form @submit.prevent="subscribeToNewsletter">
            <div class="flex flex-col">
                <div class="flex">
                    <input
                        v-model="form.email"
                        type="text"
                        name="post_title"
                        class="
                            border-primary
                            focus:border-primary
                            focus:ring-offset-transparent
                            focus:ring-transparent
                        "
                        id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                        placeholder="Your E-mail"
                    />
                    <input
                        type="submit"
                        value="Subscribe"
                        :disabled="form.processing"
                        class="px-5 py-2 bg-primary text-white cursor-pointer"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: [],
    components: {

    },
    data() {
        return {
            form: this.$inertia.form({
                email: "",
            }),
        };
    },
    methods: {
        subscribeToNewsletter() {
            this.form
                .transform((data) => ({
                    ...data,
                    // remember: this.form.remember ? "on" : "",
                }))
                .post(this.route("newsletter.store"), {
                    onSuccess: (data) => {
                        console.log("data", data);
                    },
                    onError: (data) => {
                        console.log("data", data);
                    },
                });
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

**The controller**

```
NewsletterController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\NewsletterStoreRequest;
use App\Models\Newsletter;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class NewsletterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(NewsletterStoreRequest $request)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'suss',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**The request file**

```
NewsletterStoreRequest.php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class NewsletterStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => ['required', 'max:150', 'email'],
        ];
    }
}
```

**The Route**

```
web.php

Route::post('/newsletter', [
    NewsletterController::class,
    'store',
])->name('newsletter.store');
```

In the sample above i return a json object, which is not accepted and gives me this error
[image]

I have tried following the inertia documentation about responses [here](https://inertiajs.com/responses) I think the correct answer is to be found there, I have not been able to solve it on my own

I have also looked into inertia Jetstream docs without any luck [here](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/stacks/inertia.html#form-validation-helpers)

I don't want to return a new view, I actually want it to work as an ajax request I guess where a call-back is either giving me the error or success without reloading the page or anything like that.

I see that many people have this problem, does anyone know whats going wrong and what i have to return in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me i had to change the controller to this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Inertia\Inertia;
use App\Models\Newsletter;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\Http\Requests\NewsletterStoreRequest;

class NewsletterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(NewsletterStoreRequest $request)
    {
        Newsletter::create([
            'email' => $request->email
        ]);

        return back()->with('flash', [
            'message' => 'success',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

What you should note here is this part:

```
    return back()->with('flash', [
        'message' => 'success',
    ]);
```

I found a sample where my problem was achieved with the help from a friend of mine in: `vendor/laravel/jetstream/src/Http/Controllers/Inertia/ApiTokenController.php`

Here they return with a flash message like my example above, the message key will be in props->components->flash->message

[image]

It won't work as I thought like ajax, because it uses Vue routes so the page will reload on submit.

I hope someone will find this useful.

Also if you get a console error because you use data in a vue component you have to make a check on the wrapper to check if the data is null like so:

```
<ul
   v-if="assets != null"
   class="
   marketcap-rows
   border-l border-r border-gray-200
   flex flex-col
   "
   >
   <li
      v-for="asset in $props.assets.data"
      v-bind:key="asset"
      class="
      bg-white
      grid
      gap-4
      border-t border-gray-200
      "
      >
   </li>
</ul>
```

This is the check I'm talking about: `v-if="assets != null"`

Answer (score 1):

This is how to access jetstream initial default flash message:

```
session()->flash('flash',  [
    'bannerStyle'=> 'danger',
    'banner' => 'this is the first message',
]);
return Inertia::render('Admin/Overview', [
    'users'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that to your Render...

doc: [https://inertiajs.com/shared-data#flash-messages](https://inertiajs.com/error-handling)

```
class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
    {
        public function share(Request $request)
        {
            return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
                'flash' => [
                    'message' => fn () => $request->session()->get('message')
                ],
            ]);
        }
    }
```