# Laravel Inertia apps doesn't support subdomain redirects - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: laravel, http, routes, cors, inertiajs

I'm working on a Laravel 9, InertiaJS and vue project where a user can submit a new product through `products/create` route and this sends to ProductController@store which does all what it's supposed to do and then supposedly redirect the user to the newly created product on a subdomain route like this `http://username.example.test/my-new-product`

The issue I'm having is that I keep getting the below error and the redirect doesn't work:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://user.example.test/my-first-product' (redirected from 'http://example.test/products/create') from origin 'http://example.test' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**The code works as follows:**

#### 1- The form:

```js
const form = useForm("createProduct", {
    webshop_id: null,
    title: null,
    price: null,
    type: null,
    currency: null,
    description: null,
    thumbnail: null,
});
```

```js
const submit = () => {
    form.post(route("products.create"), {
        onSuccess: () => form.reset(),
    });
};
```

#### 2- Products create router:

```php
Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified',
])->group(function () {

    Route::post('products/create', [ProductController::class, 'store'])->name('products.create');

});
```

#### 3- The controller - Storing the new product with user details and redirecting (which doesn't work) to show the product

```php
public function store(StoreProductRequest $request)
    {
        
        // Code
        
        return redirect()->route('products.show', [$user, $product]);
    }
```

#### 4- The show route and controller@show

```php
Route::domain('{user:username}.' . env('APP_URL'))->group(function () {
    Route::get('{product:slug}', [ProductController::class, 'show'])->name('products.show');
});
```

```php
    public function show(User $user, Product $product)
    {

        return Inertia::render('Products/Show', [
            'user' => $user,
            'product' => $product,
            'thumbnails' => $product->productimages
        ]);
    }
```

I saw @reinink explain in this [Issue](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/issues/99) that we can use now Inertia::location

The only way I could get this to work is returning this is the ProductController@store:

```php
 return Inertia::location('http://' . $user->username . '.example.test/' . $validated['slug']);
```

But It causes a full page refresh which defeats the whole concept of having a single page application and I will have to remember changing 'http' to 'https' and domain to the real domain when I'm going to put the app in production. I was hoping that I was doing something wrong but after hours of searching for a solution I began to think that Laravel Inertia apps doesn't support subdomain redirects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that solved for me the CORS errors from this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65535729/all-inertia-requests-must-receive-a-valid-inertia-response-however-a-plain-json)

Making those changes to cors.php solved that for me:

```php
    'paths' => ['api/*', '*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => ['x-inertia'],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

but I'm facing an issue where it redirects me to a url that ignores the subdomain completely. Find the new issue [here please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72969487/subdomain-routing-not-working-in-laravel-9-and-inertia)